# Web Development: Dynamically linking to other related webpages

Tags: java, python, html, mysql, server

I've almost 'finished' my **first** website. Which consists of an authors anthology, essentially 100's of pages containing individual articles. It's built with HTML and CSS.

At the bottom of each page I want to link to related pages, displaying the title and an image. How can I auto-populate these boxes by fetching related pages from a database?

I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, I will try to teach myself. I assume there would be some server side scripting? or loading the data into a sql?

Comment: This is too broad a question for this site. Use a discussion site, such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches.
Lets compare and contrast!

---

## 1. Server Side:

You write code on the server (in PHP or Python or Java or whatever) to create HTML files programmatically, which will have the relevant links.

Pros:

- You are in full control

Cons:

- Resource intensive (relatively speaking)
- Longer initial loading time (waiting for server to create a new page, per request)

It's the way it was always done.

---

## 2. Client Side:

You write code on the client (browser) that [receives from the server just the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (perhaps JSON?), and figures out how to display it on its own. Perhaps using [Angular](https://angular.io/), or [React](https://reactjs.org/).

Pros:

- Very light-weight on the server
- HTML pages can be hosted cheaply (S3, DropBox, what have you)

Cons:

- Content is fetched and analyzed on the fly, making the page feel slow if you're not careful
- Bloats the front end, kinda harder to grasp

---

As a sub-topic of the *Client Side*, There's a new hotness in town, and it's called [*Serverless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing). You don't have to write a back end, and you focus 100% on the front end.

If you really have to make calculations outside of the users browser you can use cloud functions (like [Amazon Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)), but I don't think that's your use case.

For your use case, you can access a database straight from the front end, without needing any back end. See: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some sort of server side program. Something that can query the database, then return the results either through an api or process it all server side and return the html. Below are some frameworks that can help.

Java:
Play, Spring, Javalin, Dropwizard, etc.

Python:
Django